# How to prevent a component from starting/rendering when the required parameters are not filled correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, components

Say I have a component and I have bindings that are not optional, like so

```js
angular.module("foo").component("fooComp", {
    bindings: {
      notOpt: "<",
    },
    templateUrl: "...",
    controllerAs: "...",
    controller: [fooCtrl],
  });
  function fooCtrl() {
    const $vm = this;

    $vm.$onInit = onInit;

    function onInit() {
      // ...
    }

  }
```

Is there a way that I can prevent the component from rendering without the help of a flag and ngIf? Something like a self destroy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is just removing the element with `$element.remove()` and then also destroying the scope with `$scope.destroy()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try "Conditional render" :D
I leave the site which tells you how to do it.
React and Angular are both JavaScript. You can do what you need with this idea :D

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-applications

If my answer helped you, pls select my answer :D

Comment: My question was if I could do it in the controller, in a way that would destroy the element and not render it, instead of using ngIf (the conditional rendering).